# Can the fusion and fission of a group of atoms occur infinitely?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, fusion

Is it possible to split a nucleus and put it back together? If so, is it feasible to do it an indefinite number of times, i.e. without them wearing out or failing to stick together once again?

Comment: In theory perhaps. Net energy output would be zero at best...

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. You seem to be asking if you can take atoms apart and put them back together again an infinite number of times, eg without them wearing out or failing to stick together again. Is that it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "simultaneous process" in this context?

Comment: I've deleted an inappropriate comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a 'what if' multi-layered question, so let's start with building the hypotheses to make this work until we can arrive at a conclusion. So what can we do to make aforementioned process to work?

- 1st scenario: We have an 'open system', that is, any energy that might be emitted is lost. This would cause the trial to fail. Any system (nucleus) has an associated energy: the rest mass of the system (in grams), and the nuclear bond energy. If this nucleus goes through fission, it breaks into two smaller and releases energy through gamma ray photons. As stated previously, this gamma ray photons would just vanish in the conditions of the experiment. Then, the total energy of the system would be fewer than of the original, making it impossible to recreate the initial nucleus.
- 2nd scenario: The system is closed, we could somehow store all the energy that is released and then reuse it in further reactions, the answer is a bothersome 'depends'. Some nuclei already do that in the nature; others don't, because the reaction of their products doesn't result in themselves.
- 2.1 scenario: The nucleus is that of the kind `initial nucleus => lighter element + lighter element`, but `lighter element + lighter element =X=> initial nucleus`. Then no, if we take for example `Lithium-7 + proton`, it would result in `Lithium-7 + proton => Beryllium-8`, beryllium-8 then, would be likely to decay in attoseconds into two nuclei of Helium-4. And it doesn't matter how you smash those two Helium-4 together, they will form Beryllium-8 again only for the latter to disband once again, never returning to the `Lithium-7 + proton` state.  Other examples are possible, such as `H-2 + H-3 => H-4 + proton`, but `H-4 + proton =X=> H-2 + H-3`.
- 2.1.1: Curiosity: the addition of one more Helium-4 to the Be-8 would create Carbon-12, just like the Helium-fusion reactions that are only found in stars, the Triple-alpha process. Alpha being the name of a Helium-4 nucleus, see: alpha radiation, triple because there are three "alpha's" involved
- 2.2 scenario: The nucleus is that of the kind `initial nucleus => lighter element + lighter element`, and `lighter element + lighter element => initial nucleus`. Then it is very possible, and it even happens in nature itself. Remember the cycle `Be-8 => He-4 + He-4 => Be-8 =>...`? There you have it, smash two Helium-4's together and you have Be-8, which will undergo fission to generate two He-4, which could be fused again to finally create a cycle of fusion-fission; actually, this already happens in Helium-fusing stars, until the Be-8 successfully fuses with another He-4 to form Carbon. Other examples are possible, such as `Lithium-4 => Helium-3 + proton => Lithium-4`.

Note: proton and Hydrogen-1 are used as the same thing, a proton alone.

Note 2: H-2 =  Deuterium; H-3 = Tritium; H-4 = Hydrogen-4

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious to understand if you can split a nucleus

splitting a nucleus releases energy as radiation and kinetic of fragments.

> or multiple nuclei and combine them back together through fusion,

some of the fragments may possibly fuse while again releasing  energy in radiation and kinetic energy of fragments.

This is a statistical process, to get fusion of low mass fragments will have a probability for the first rounds  of the process,( those two particle ones with no radiation). Fusion over the iron in the [binding energy curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve) will be very improbable because the probability of getting three  or more large  fragments together (including electromagnetic radiation) will be infinitesimally small.

[image: nbind]

As time goes on  a large part of the energy will be radiation, and  at some point in time there will be not enough energy  for fission  of the low mass nuclei, and the system will stabilize into radiation and stable nuclei below the Fe in the binding energy curve.

In other words entropy increases, the order of the beginning cannot be regained.